# How do I convert a DateTime to a Date in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-4.0

I can't believe how long it's taken me to fail at finding the answer to this seemingly obvious question.

```
Date SomeRandomMadeUpDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(randomMonths).Date;
```

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Date'
>   I can even call:

```
Date.Now
```

but calling `.AddDays` on it returns a `DateTime`.

Again, the question is: How do I turn a C# `DateTime` into a C# `Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to look it up, because I didn't know there was a Date-type in .NET 4.0, but apparently there is one in System.Dataflow.dll. Just use the constructor, with the DateTime as the argument:

```
Date d = new Date(dt);
```

Answer (score 12):

There is no "Date" type as such.  It's all DateTimes.  It's just that when you call .Date, you are getting that DateTime as of midnight on that day.

If you're talking about the "Date" data type in VB.NET, that's the same thing as DateTime, believe it or not.

Comment: @tehp: you cannot obtain such a error, because the "Date" from DateTime.Now.AddMonths(randomMonths).**Date**; is a **DateTime**.

Comment: @ Meta-Knight in VB both type are in fact DateTime, in vb.NET date is used for compatibility

Comment: Perhaps he has a Date class defined somewhere.  Nothing in the question suggests the Date class exists in the System namespace.

Comment: @serhio: Yes, I assumed it was the same in C# but I see that I was mistaken. If it's not the same type then it explains the error...

Comment: @yodaj007: Are you sure? -> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'System.Date'

Comment: @yoda007: Yes it does -- in the error message.  It looks like someone has defined a System.Date somewhere.  @tehp: Right click and select "Go to Definition" on your Date class.  That should give you a clue.

Answer (score 11):

.NET doesn't have a type representing just a date - it's problems like this that made me start [Noda Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time) (which isn't even nearly ready for production yet).

[`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) returns another [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) with the same date as the original, but at midnight. That's basically the closest there is to a `Date` type in .NET :( Note that if you want *today's* date then [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) is a simpler way of calling `DateTime.Now.Date`.

I've no idea why the compiler is giving an error message that suggests there *is* a `System.Date` type - it doesn't on my machine:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Date today = DateTime.Now.Date;
    }
}
```

Gives this error:

> Test.cs(7,9): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name 'Date' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Can you give a similar short but complete program which shows the error message you're getting? Do you have some other library referenced which *does* have a `System.Date` type? (As Tommy Carlier suggests, perhaps `System.Dataflow`?)

Comment: System.Dataflow.dll (part of SQL Server Modeling) has a type System.Date.

Comment: @Tommy: That was my suspicion (see edit :) - that's frankly horrible. Something that's SQL Server specific shouldn't be contributing to the `System` namespace :(

Comment: There.  I have a reference to System.Dataflow.  I guess it should be a DateTime

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a new `Date` object from a `DateTime` object:

```
Date d = new Date(DateTime.Now);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.date.date(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following

```
string onlyDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

this will return Only the date as a string so i think you can use it as

```
 Date dateNow = new Date(onlyDate );
```